# What does this phrase mean ‘so much for something’?

Tags: meaning

I was reading an article on ESPN and at the end it said ‘so much for team loyalty’.

Can anyone explain what this means?

Comment: "An expression of disregard, or resignation; something said upon giving up, quitting, or disposing of something." [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/so_much_for)

Comment: This phrase can be looked up on the Internet. It's in lots of dictionaries. Start [here](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/so-much-for-sth). This should be closed as a general reference question. Please do some basic research before asking this kind of dictionary question.

Answer (score 2):

It is a dismissive expression, conveying the rueful sentiment that someone is not living up to certain principles — in this case, team loyalty.

To reword it in a mechanically plain fashion, it is the equivalent of saying

> This is how little people think or pay attention to the important, perhaps even essential quality known as team loyalty. I am appalled.